# Create sharepoint list using azure logic apps

Tags: sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

I want to create a list from an excel sheet I am uploading to SharePoint using Azure Logic Apps. Now I want to use this app to update a list on SharePoint using the same excel file. It is getting executed but gives absurd values in the list. Please help me to know how can I make this work.  [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is because you just pass the file content not the items, the logic app won't do data processing, you need design you flow to process the data then create item one by one.

Below is my test flow, I get the csv file from SharePoint then I use **Plumsail** `Parse CSV` action to get the items. If you are processing other excel file you could use excel connector to get rows.

[image]

Here is my test result.

[image]

Comment: is there any way to do it without specifying each header ? The columns in my csv file will keep on increasing and that would mean I have to update the Header in parse json every time I have a new file.

Comment: Suppose for now this is not possible, mostly you want to trigger when a row is updated, for now the mostly connectors only support the file update trigger to get the whole file content, if that you have to  process the full data not only the new part.

Comment: @SarveshAhuja, if this could help you, you could accept it as the answer. Thanks!